# How can I find days between different paired rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been racking my brain about how to do this in one query without PHP code.

In a nutshell, I have a table that records email activity.  For the sake of this example, here is the data:

```
recipient_id     activity     date
1                delivered    2011-08-30
1                open         2011-08-31
2                delivered    2011-08-30
3                delivered    2011-08-24
3                open         2011-08-30
3                open         2011-08-31
```

The goal: I want to display to users a single number that tells how many recipients open their email within 24 hours.

E.G.  "Users that open their email within 24 hours: 13 Readers"

In the case of the sample data, above, the value would be "1".  (Recipient one was delivered an email and opened it the next day.  Recipient 2 never opened it and recipient 3 waited 5 days.)

Can anyone think of a way to express the goal in a single query?

Reminder: In order to count, the person must have a 'delivered' tag and at least one 'open' tag.   Each 'open' tag only counts once per recipient.

** EDIT **  Sorry, I'm using MySQL

Comment: which database and version is this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version in mysql.

```
select count(distinct recipient_id)
from email e1
where e1.activity = 'delivered'
  and exists
        (select * from email e2
         where e1.recipient_id = e2.recipient_id
           and e2.activity = 'open'
           and datediff(e2.action_date,e1.action_date) <= 1)
```

The basic principle is that you want to find a delivered row for a recipient that also has an open within 24 hours.

The `datediff()` is a good way to do the date arithmetic in mysql -- other dbs will vary on exact methods for this step.  The rest of the sql will work anywhere.

SQLFiddle here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9116/4

Comment: I appreciate all of the great replies!  I tried several of them and Mike's query was the most optimal!  Thanks Mike and everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but should work ;) Don't know which SQL dialect you use, so I've used TSQL  [DATEDIFF](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp) function.

```
select distinct opened.recipient_id -- or count(distinct opened.recipient_id) if you want to know number
from actions as opened 
inner join actions as delivered 
on opened.recipient_id = delivered.recipient_id and delivered.activity = 'delivered'
where opened.activity = 'open' and DATEDIFF(day, delivered.date, opened.date) <= 1
```

Edit: I'd confused opened with delivered - now replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions: MySql, table is called "TABLE"

Ok, I am not 100% on this, because I don't have a copy of the table to run it against, but I think that you could do something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t1.recipient_id) FROM TABLE t1
INNER JOIN TABLE t2 ON t1.recipient_id = t2.recipient_id AND t1.activity != t2.activity
WHERE t1.activity in ('delivered', 'open') AND t2.activity in ('delivered', 'open')
AND ABS(DATEDIFF(t1.date, t2.date)) = 1
```

Basically, you are joining a table onto itself, where the activities don't match, but recipient_ids do, and the status is either 'delivered' or 'open'.  What you would end up getting, is a result that looks like this:

```
1 delivered 2011-08-30 1 open 2011-08-31
```

You are then doing a diff between the two dates (with an absolute value, because we don't know which order they will be in) and making sure that it is equal to 1 (or 24 hours).